# how to remove extra space in json output from lambda

Tags: python, pandas, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-data-wrangler

I have a lambda reading csv's in an S3 bucket. The api gateway calls the lambda.
The data in the csv is like this:

```
Ticker  Exchange    Date        Open    High    Low     Close   Volume
6A      BATS        12/2/2021   0.9     0.95    0.83    0.95    1200
6B      BATS        12/3/2021   1       1.3     0.9     1.2     1500
6C      BATS        12/4/2021   1.2     1.3     1.1     1.1     1300
```

here is my code:

```
import json
import awswrangler as wr

BUCKET_NAME = 'olaptrader-products'
DIRECTORY_PATH = '1'
FULL_PATH = f"s3://{BUCKET_NAME}/{DIRECTORY_PATH}"

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    raw_df = wr.s3.read_csv(path=FULL_PATH, path_suffix=['.csv'], use_threads=True)
    df = raw_df.to_json(orient="records")
    parsed = json.loads(df)

    return {
      "statusCode": 200,
      'body': json.dumps(parsed)
    }
```

My output looks like this:

```
[{"Ticker": "6A", "Exchange": "BATS", "Date": "12/2/2021", "Open": 0.9, "High": 0.95, "Low": 0.83, "Close": 0.95, "Volume": 1200}, {"Ticker": "6B", "Exchange": "BATS", "Date": "12/3/2021", "Open": 1.0, "High": 1.3, "Low": 0.9, "Close": 1.2, "Volume": 1500}, {"Ticker": "6C", "Exchange": "BATS", "Date": "12/4/2021", "Open": 1.2, "High": 1.3, "Low": 1.1, "Close": 1.1, "Volume": 1300}]
```

How do I get rid of those extra spaces? I have tried "skipinitialspace" in the df.to_json, but that apparently is not for json, only csv and so, it didnt work.
I dont want to get rid of ALL spaces, because there will be situations where I have a company name in there with a space and I want to keep that. Just need to get rid of these leading spaces.
Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but I can't see the "extra spaces" you mention. They don't seem to be in the Output you have provided.

Comment: after the "Ticker": and before "6A", is the first occurrence

Comment: The space is produced by the `json.dumps()` command, when it converts to the objects to a string representation. See the linked 'duplicate' question for details on how to modify the conversion to a string.

Comment: Thanks John. Sorry about the dupe.